# How do I use the same functions on different data frames?

Tags: r, loops

I have 30 data sets for everyday of month and i want to analysis them individually, giving me one result value for every day. Is it possible to loop the data sets, that operations are conducted on each data set and 30 resultant values are complied together in a new data frame.

More specifically, i have 96 readings for every day and for example i want to know there mean, max and min. So, using apply i can get it for 1 day then i will have to do it 30 times or i can create a function and call it 30 times. is there any simpler way around repetitive work.

Comment: Can't you use `sapply( datasets, yourFunction)`?

Comment: actual sample data would help, but if you can `fn <- list.files("dir")` then you can `dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(fn, function(x) { dat <- read.csv(x); ## do stuff and return a data frame ## }))`. More specifics as an answer the better the question details get.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy.  Set your working directory to where the files are.  The get the files with `list.files()` and store them.  Then write a function which reads in a file and returns a data.frame with the info you want.  Then use `sapply` on the list of files calling the function you made, e.g.:

```
setwd("C:\some_dir")
days = list.files()
someFunction = function(day){
    data = read.csv(day)
    return(data.frame(Mean=mean(data),SD=sd(data)))
}
sapply(days,someFunction)
```